# Pandas Python: read_excel: Is it possible to only read the column headers in a certain data type (read the headers as strings)?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataset in which some of the column names are numbers (integer or with fractions), I want to keep the names as it is, but read_excel makes all of them float.

Can I declare only the headers as string? (With headers and dtype?)

Here in this call, I want to make column headers str.

```py
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',
                   sheet_name='sheet1',
                   index_col=None,
                   dtype = str ,
                   engine='openpyxl')
```

If this is not possible,

can I make the 0th row string (no headers but the first row to be string) while reading the data which would give me the column names as strings?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```py
# with this setting your header will be pushed down to be your first row
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=None)

# use 1st row to set your column names
df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0])

# reset the index
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Note: `dtype` keyword is meant to specify the data type that dictates the data type of the **data** in the entire dataframe or if a dict is assigned, then individual columns will have that specified datatype.

> dtypeType name or dict of column -> type, default None
>
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} Use
> object to preserve data as stored in Excel and not interpret dtype. If
> converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

Comment: This worked, but I had to make a few changes: delete the first row after renaming, and add inplace=True in all calls. `df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], inplace=True)
df.drop(labels=0, axis=0, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`