# How to stop changing pandas from changing the column name into date format?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a excel file with header with month-Year format. It changes it to date-time. How can I stop it from reading it as date time and force it to read as string instead.

test.xlsx

[image: Data looks like this in excel file]

When I read it as

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
```

This is what it reads as:

[image: This is what I see]

I would like it to read as:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Python: read\_excel: Is it possible to only read the column headers in a certain data type (read the headers as strings)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065746/pandas-python-read-excel-is-it-possible-to-only-read-the-column-headers-in-a-c)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. It fix the problem. It still reads the file as the date instead of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be bit of a workaround and specific to your case. But, I tried it and it works. Steps are:

1. Read the dataframe and remove the UserID column to a temp series
2. Transpose the datetime only dataframe, which will bring the columns as index
3. Use `strftime()` to convert this to string with format you need
4. Transpose again and add UserID column to the start

```
uid = df['UserID'] ## Read User ID to a temp variable
df.drop(columns='UserID', axis=1, inplace=True) ##Drop User ID, leaving only datetime colums
df= df.T ## Transpose, will bring datetime as index
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%b-%y') ##Conver index to string
df=df.T  ## Transpose back
df.insert(loc=0, column='UserID', value=uid)  ## Add UserID to loc=0
print(df)

 UserID Jan-21  Feb-21  Mar-21  Apr-21
0   1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5   6
2   3   4   5   6   7
3   4   5   6   7   8
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try reading column into string object by specifying the `dtype` parameter as covered in documentation (linked below).

[https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#:~:text=dtypeType%20name%20or%20dict%20of%20column%20%2D%3E%20type%2C%20default%20None](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#:%7E:text=dtypeType%20name%20or%20dict%20of%20column%20%2D%3E%20type%2C%20default%20None)

If you also set the `header=None` option you can then set the first row to be a header after the fact and change the types according to your needs.

Comment: Yeah I set header = None and set the first header. df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',header=None,dtype=object) . It still reads as date

Comment: Maybe try making all cols strings to start. i.e. `dtype={col: 'str' for col in range(n_cols)}`.